# Не могу найти файлы .html в dle.

Tags: html, dle

Привет, на сайте есть страницы с адресом: `example.ru/russian/name.html`. Вот что находится в корне сайта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть, папки russian и поблизости нет. Я также перебрал все каталоги, и файлы с расширением `.html` не увидел.
Как можно найти контроллер который за все это отвечает?

Comment: `name.php ` в поиск вбей

Comment: Если просто изменить расширение в урле, то ошибка Not Found

Comment: Я про файловую систему

Comment: Там даже файлов с таким именем нет, я уже не говорю про расширение

Comment: как насчет поиска по содержимому всех файлов по запросу "russian"?

Comment: В `.htaccess` правила посмотри

Comment: Поиск по содержимому файлов?